# Toggle HTML radio button by clicking its label

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

Is there please a simple way to make a radio button toggle - when a text near it is clicked - without introducing any big Javascript Framework into my smal PHP project?

The web form looks like this:

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post">
<p>Mode:<br /> 
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="create"><i>create table</i><br />
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="select" checked>select records (can specify id)<br />
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="insert">insert 1 record (must specify all)<br />
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="delete">delete records (must specify id)<br />
<input type="radio" name="mode" value="drop"><i>drop table</i><br />
</p>
<p>Id: <input type="text" name="id" size=32 maxlength=32 /> (32 hex chars)</p>

<p>Latitude: <input type="text" name="lat" size=10 /> (between -90 and 90)</p>
<p>Longitude: <input type="text" name="lng" size=10 /> (between -90 and 90)</p>
<p>Speed: <input type="text" name="spd" size=10 /> (not negative)</p>
<p><input type="submit" value="OK" /></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: If anyone else came here wondering why their label wasn't working: Make sure you added an id, not just a value to your radio button 

Answer (score 191, accepted):

You can also wrap your elements *without* giving them each an ID, since a `<label>` is implicitly for the input it contains, like this:

```
<label>
   <input type="radio" name="mode" value="create">
   <i>create table</i>
</label>
```

Comment: This makes styling the label more difficult and requires you wrap your text in even more elements.

Comment: Yes, but if you're not styling, it makes it easier to get the functionality you want. I don't like having to add extra ID and "for" attributes.

Comment: +1 IDs can be very evil so best to avoid them as a general rule

Comment: wrapping is a superior solution to using `id` and `for` with no wrapping. The reason is that if the label has wide margin and the user happens to click in the sweet spot between the checkbox and the label (as they are most likely to do) then nothing happens. Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/v157ctja/5/

Comment: What do you do when input is in your table? How do you apply labels in that case? I'm now using labels in each `<td>` using `id` and `for`. Where should I use the label so that the styling won't change?

Answer (score 95):

You can use [`<label>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp) elements, which are designed to do exactly that:

```
<input type="radio" id="radCreateMode" name="mode" value="create" />
<label for="radCreateMode"><i>create table</i></label>
```

Comment: @Alexander, absolutely. Only Safari version 2 and lower doesn't support it.

Comment: And thereafter you can use the selector `input#radCreateMode:checked ~ label` to apply styles to the label. Applying styles to labels upon selection is not possible if we nest the input inside the label.

Comment: This really should be the accepted answer, it's the proper way to do this.

Comment: I'm using Safari v 13 and this method did not work for me.  The radio button could be deselected, but not selected.  I had to wrap the label around the input: <label><input>my label text</label>.   Note that I am not using a <form>, nor a <fieldset>.

Comment: Make sure the for attribute value is the correct id for the input. Just in case if someone made the same mistake as me.

Comment: This solution is a possible issue in long forms with many inputs, such as tests / quizzes or similar, you would need lots of ids to link input and label, which is an extra work and maybe complexity

Answer (score 7):

Wrapping the input under the label should work.

```
<label>
    <input type="radio" name="mode" value="create"><i>create table</i>
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had trouble finding the value of the radio button using this method, an alternative is to use a hit area [increasing clickable area of a button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246893/increasing-clickable-area-of-a-button).