# Tool to spot invisible SVG canvas obscuring other page elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to use radio buttons to control the layout of a page.  The buttons look like this:

```
<form>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="layout" class='layout-controls' data-type='layout' data-value='one'>
    One
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="layout" class='layout-controls' data-type='layout' data-value='two'>
    Two
  </label>
</form>
```

And I'm binding a function like this:

```
$('.layout-controls').on('click', function(event) {
  var $btn;
  $btn = $(event.target);
  return doStuff($btn.data('type'), $btn.data('value'));
});
```

This all works fine.

Then I'm trying to add elements to a higher part of page after the event handler has been bound:

```
$("#message-area").html("<div><br><br><p>Please make a selection </p></div>")
```

This causes the radio buttons to become unclickable. Some observations:

- A tool like [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/visual+event+2) can still see the correct event handlers on each radio button, and trigger them
- The more HTML tags are added in the `message-area` the more of the radio buttons below become unclickable
- It feels like inserting these elements is somehow "shunting" something down the page
- Rather than using JQuery to insert the elements I tried `getElementById` and `innerHTML` but is seemed to make no difference

Can you shed any light on what is happening here?  Should I be able to insert HTML further up a page after the event handlers have been bound?  What is the safe and robust way to do this?

**EDIT**

So it turns out that the insertion of the text was shunting a rogue, invisible SVG canvas over the radio buttons (see [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/derekhill/SvgK4/)).  I found this because I spotted it in the markup which took ages because there are many elements on the page.  Having found it I can obviously fix it, but I was wondering, is there a tool that could have made this visible or helped with debugging this?

Comment: fiddle? link? `Can you shed any light on what is happening here?`

Comment: `It feels like inserting these elements is somehow "shunting" something down the page` is that supposed to mean something?

Comment: if the message-area is supposed to be on top of the area it's in and you still want the other stuff pushed under it - use .prepend() instead of .html().

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight spent ages trying to replicate this in a fiddle and in doing so found the problem (see edit).  I made the comment about "shunting" something down the page because of the observation that the more HTML was inserted the more radio buttons were inactivated.  Now we know this was a blank SVG canvas.

Comment: im glad to be of help, my comment meant: this is programming `It feels` aint gonna get u far. (until some sort of `sci-fi` era in which the computer will sense our feelings and build a program for us.....). in the future use a developer tool, i recommend `firebug` - its a `firefox` add-on, but you can use the default one in chrome as well, or any of the many other ones out there... programming without one is a huge Achilles heel.

Comment: @tryingToGetProgrammingStraight I'm using Firebug. I thing the root of this problem is that it doesn't show blank SVG canvases by default and I haven't figured out how to get it to do so.

Comment: oh, well cool then...

Comment: http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/inspection/

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to set the message UNDER the form like this ?

Edit: you can use that

```
$("#message-area").html("<div><br><br><p>Please make a selection </p></div>");
```

OR:

```
 $("#message-area").html("<div><br><br><p>Please make a selection </p></div>");

<form>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="layout" class='layout-controls' data-type='layout' data-value='one'>
    One
  </label>
  <label>
    <input type="radio" name="layout" class='layout-controls' data-type='layout' data-value='two'>
    Two
  </label>
</form>
<div id="message-area"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I could have done this but the page layout doesn't work this way.  Turns out the cause was a rogue SVG canvas (see edit above)

Answer (score 0):

```
<form>
    <input id="input1" type="radio1" name="layout" class="layout-controls" data-type="layout" data-value="one">
    <label for="input1">One</label>
    <input id="input2" type="radio2" name="layout" class="layout-controls" data-type="layout" data-value="two">
    <label for="input2">Two</label>
</form>
```

Add ids to your inputs and set for-attributes to your labels. don't put the input controls within the label tags. not tested.

The labels with a "for" attribute do have a logic link to the input control. You don't have to to put the input inside the label for the click feature. I guess your JS problem is caused by this structure.

Comment: Thanks.  The reason I put the input controls within the label tags is so that [clicking the labels also activates the controls](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4213253/1450420)