# CSS :before pseudo selector and increasing the area of an <a> tag

Tags: html, css, z-index

I'm creating an image slider, and I want the "previous" and "next" arrows to each take up half the area of the slider. Increasing padding or margins tends to shift the position of the arrow after I've placed it.

The closest solution I found is to use the :before pseudo selector as [per this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19246893/increasing-clickable-area-of-a-button). This will work well enough but I am open to other suggestions from the community, as the current approach feels a bit "hacky."

Using this approach, I am trying to set up each arrow to take up exactly half of the slider box, but I can't figure out how to keep these areas responsive to the window width.

**Please view this fiddle** and resize the window.

http://jsfiddle.net/amoeboar/avqjnfwt/1/

I want the clickable area halves to always take up half the slider window, and not reposition the arrows.

```
.prev:before{
    position:absolute;
    content:'';
    top: -40%;
    right: -235%;
    left: -40%;
    bottom: -120%;
    outline:1px solid red;
    z-index:40;
}
```

This doesn't work though. Firstly, setting negative percentages seems strange, and second of all, resizing the window does not preserve the shape and size of the clickable area like I am hoping. I want the left arrow to take up exactly half of the bounding box, and the right arrow to do the same.

Can anyone make a suggestion?

Comment: That will almost work for me, except I don't want to move the position of the arrows. They have been placed at a specific location relative to the black box and I only want to change the clickable area such that it takes up half the box.

Comment: Positioning the arrows is just a matter of changing the padding of the `<a>` elements. [This fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/avqjnfwt/3/) has them at the same position you had them.

Comment: Beautiful solution, thank you very much!

Comment: OK, I'll write that up as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements on the links; they only make things more difficult to maintain.

The real solution is to simply position the `<a>`s themselves to the screen areas where you want them, and to use padding inside each `<a>` to position the arrow.

```css
.prev,
.next {
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    left:0; right:50%;
    top:0; bottom:0;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: salmon;
    font-size: 8em;
    outline:1px solid red;
    padding:70px 40px;
}

.next {
    left:50%; right:0;
    text-align:right;
    transform:scaleY(-1);
}
```

That's all. Because the `<a>`s are already positioned absolutely, you won't need the `z-index`; they are already on top.

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MrLister/avqjnfwt/5/).

By the way, you shouldn't use `<` in texts in HTML, use `&lt;`.