# How to integrate php code in radio buttons?

Tags: php, html, radio-button

I am working on a radio buttons (which looks like a toggle button) in which I want to integrate php code. Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/des35wyv/4/embedded/result) for the radio buttons which I am using in my code base.

The snippets of code which I have used in the fiddle is pasted below. I have also placed condition (not included in the fiddle) with the php code for **On/Off**.

```
<td valign="top">
   <fieldset style="background-color:#EDADFF;">
      <legend><strong>Homepage Tiles</strong></legend>
      <input type="radio" id="toggle-on" value="3" name="toggle_status" <?php if($data->{"toggle_status"}==3){echo
         'checked';}?>/>
      <label for="toggle-on">On</label>
      <input type="radio" id="toggle-off" value="0" name="toggle_status" <?php if($data->{"toggle_status"}==0){echo
         'checked';}?> />
      <label for="toggle-off">Off</label>
   </fieldset>
</td>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering **if($data->{"toggle_status"}==3)** (meaning when toggle is **on**), how I can integrate my php code then.

The snippets of php code which I want to integrate when **if($data->{"toggle_status"}==3)** is:

```
<?php
$special_reports = new \WP_Query( [
    'post_type' => 'current-special-report',
    'orderby'   => 'menu_order',
    'order'     => 'ASC',
    'posts_per_page' => 2,
]);
switch(ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE){
    case 'en':
        $url = "http://www.current.ca/en/current-in-focus/";
        $url_ess = "http://www.current.ca/en/programs/lessentiel-with-esther-begin/";
        $url_ptp = "http://www.current.ca/en/programs/primetime-politics/";
        $url_out = "http://www.current.ca/en/programs/outburst/";
        $url_per = "http://www.current.ca/en/programs/perspective-with-alison-smith/";
        $link_view = "View All";
        break;
    case 'fr':
        $url = "http://www.current.ca/fr/dossiers-current/";
        $url_ess = "http://www.current.ca/fr/programs/lessentiel-avec-esther-begin/";
        $url_ptp = "http://www.current.ca/fr/programs/lheure-politique/";
        $url_out = "http://www.current.ca/fr/programs/outburst/";
        $url_per = "http://www.current.ca/fr/programs/perspective-avec-alison-smith/";
        $link_view = "Toutes";
        break;
}


$horizontal_class = ( get_query_var( 'current_in_depth_full', false ) ) ? '-horizontal': '';

// Mon-Thur Essentiel/PTP
// Fri-Sun Persp/Outburst
$arradate = strtolower(date('D'));
date_default_timezone_set('America/Toronto');
$nowtime = date('H:i:s');
$tue_thu = array('tue','wed','thu');
?>
```

Comment: This might help; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4213172/toggle-html-radio-button-by-clicking-its-label

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand the point. PHP is a mainly a server-side language to help dynamically building your content. 
When the server will deliver the page php will test your $data and check the radiobutton accordingly.
Once the page is in the browser, the browser will do it itself and there is no need of php there.
If you want any changes to be done to the page by php depending on the toogle, you have to submit it to php (ie to the server) so that the server knows the user choice and provides an updated page.
Otherwise you have to use a client-side language (javascript or I don't know what else)